# how to put quote around variable in shell script

Tags: shell-script

My code is as below,

```
file="test.text"
while IFS= read line
do
        # display $line or do somthing with $line
    x="\'$line\'"
    echo $x
    # sleep 10

done <"$file"
```

However, this one gives me following result.

```
\'google.com
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `x="\'${line}\'"` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The escape characters are not needed for a single quote within double quotes.  Double quotes already escape single quotes.  Just use:

```
x="'${line}'"
```

Comment: It gives me following out put `'google.com`, it doesn't add quote around end

Comment: @KppatelPatel: what are the contents of `test.text`?

Comment: file that is converted from CSV to text, each line is just url

Comment: @KppatelPatel: I think you have a typo somewhere in your code that isn't displayed here than because it works fine for me.

Comment: It seems like something is wrong when I convert csv to text file, when I diligently copy data from file to another file, it worked.

Comment: What type of system are you working on and what are you using to convert?  It's possible that you are getting dos/mac line endings and may need to dos2unix the file.

Comment: i am using mac, I didn't use any special program, i just went into my file, and remove all `,` and then save as .text file

Comment: @KppatelPatel: If you used a gui app on your mac to edit then it added `^M` line endings which don't work with unix scripts.  You will need to use `mac2unix` on the file (part of the `dos2unix` package)